# reindex (1,N) dimension dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matrix, indexing, series

```
A = pandas.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 4], "Output1" : [6, 8]}).set_index(["A"]).fillna(0)
new_A = A.reindex(pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['Output1', "-"]]) , axis="columns")
```

I'm expecting to get

```
  Output1
        -
A        
1       6
4       8
```

But instead I get

```
  Output1
        -
A        
1     NaN
4     NaN
```

Anything wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `reindex`, which aligns the columns by names. Just reassign the columns:

```
A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['Output1', "-"]])
```

Output:

```
  Output1
        -
A        
1       6
4       8
```

Comment: totally ! nice and easy